# Getting laravel to scroll down after submit

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a contact form and I would like my page to scroll down to display my function.

My getContactUsForm function

```
public function getContactUsForm(){

    $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();
    $menu = Menu::where('id', 1)->orWhere('title', 'home')->firstOrFail(); // 30 is the home id
    $layout = $menu->type;

    $content = Content::where('id', 1)->orWhere('title', 'home')->firstOrFail();

    $main_menu = Menu::all();
    $contact_bottom = Contact::all();
    $social_media = SocialMedia::all();
    $seo = Seo::all();


    //Get all the data and store it inside Store Variable
    $data = Input::all();

    //Validation rules
    $rules = array (
        'name' => 'required|alpha',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required'
    );

    //Validate data
    $validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules);

    //If everything is correct than run passes.
    if ($validator -> passes()){

        //Send email using Laravel send function
        Mail::send('templates::emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
        //email 'From' field: Get users email add and name
        $message->from($data['email'] , $data['name']);
        //email 'To' field: cahnge this to emails that you want to be notified.
        $message->to('info@webkrunch.co.za', 'Webkrunch Info')->subject('contact request');

        });
        return response()->json('Thank you! Your message has been received');
    }else{
        //return contact form with errors
        return view('open::index', compact('menus_child', 'main_menu', 'content', 'contact_bottom', 'social_media', 'seo'))->with('menu', $menu, $main_menu, $content, $contact_bottom, $social_media)->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

and I've done a redirect back with a success message.

my js

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var subject = $('#subject').val();
  var your_message = $('#your_message').val();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: host+'/',
      data: {name:name, email:email, subject:subject, your_message:your_message},
      success: function( msg ) {
      // alert( msg );
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
        }, 600);
      }
  });
});
```

but my js doesn't work after the page was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue:

1. You're capturing the `submit` function. But it means nothing because you're not preventing the form from it's default action, which is to `POST` to the server. This will ignore your submit function.
2. When you `redirect()->back()->with('success')`, you're not doing anything. It's just going back. The `submit()` method doesn't magically fire again.

Here's your options:

1. You can use `AJAX` to perform the submission. Then you can respond back with a favorable result if everything works out. `return response()->json('Thank you! Your message has been received')`.
2. If you're not interested in AJAX, then you can check for the existence of the `$success` variable and wrap your javascript around that check.

Something like this:

```
@if(isset($success))
    <script>
    $('#contact_form').submit(function(){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
        }, 600);
    });
    </script>
@endif
```

And just place that at the bottom of the view.

**Edit**

If you're wanting to use `method 1` outlined under `Here's your options`, then you need to utilize AJAX and prevent the default form submission:

```
$('#contact_form').on('submit', function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.prop('action'),
        method: $form.prop('method'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(resp){
        $('html', 'body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top
        }, 600);

        //you can access your message in the resp object.
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: when I add `return response()->json('Thank you! Your message has been received');` I just get an echoed response. I don't get taken back to the page

Comment: @Isis As mentioned in the above post, you must be leveraging `AJAX`. Else you're going to post to the server and it's going to respond with a blank white message and that string. Which I presume is the case. Did you use AJAX?

Comment: yep I have. I've updated my question with the changes I did

Comment: @Isis I've also updated my answer with an example using AJAX which should be pretty much plug-and-play code.

Comment: @Isis I can see that the reason yours doesn't work is that you don't `return false` at the bottom. This prevents the page from still submitting to the server.